# C# Count() Extension Method Performance

Tags: c#, linq, count, extension-methods

If the LINQ `Count()` extension method is invoked on an `IEnumerable<T>` that has a `Count` property (e.g. `List<T>`), does the `Count()` method look for that property and return it (rather than counting the items by enumerating them)? The following test code seems to indicate that it does:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace CountSpeedTest
{
    // Output:
    // List      - CLR : 0 ms
    // Enumerate - CLR : 10 ms
    // List      - Mine: 12 ms
    // Enumerate - Mine: 12 ms
    class Program
    {
        private const int Runs = 10;
        private const int Items = 1000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var total = new long[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
            for (int i = 0; i < Runs; ++i)
            {
                var items = Enumerable.Range(0, Items).Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
                var list = new List<string>(items);
                var enumerate = new Enumerate<string>(items);
                total[0] += TimeCount(list, c => c.Count());
                total[1] += TimeCount(enumerate, c => c.Count());
                total[2] += TimeCount(list, c => c.SlowCount());
                total[3] += TimeCount(enumerate, c => c.SlowCount());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("List      - CLR : {0} ms", total[0] / Runs));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Enumerate - CLR : {0} ms", total[1] / Runs));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("List      - Mine: {0} ms", total[2] / Runs));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Enumerate - Mine: {0} ms", total[3] / Runs));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static long TimeCount<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<IEnumerable<T>, int> counter)
        {
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var count = counter(collection);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            if (count != Items) throw new Exception("Incorrect Count");
            return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }

    public static class CountExtensions
    {
        // Performs a simple enumeration based count.
        public static int SlowCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            var i = 0;
            var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) i++;
            return i;
        }
    }

    // Wraps an IEnumerable<T> to hide its Count property.
    public class Enumerate<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<T> collection;
        public Enumerate(IEnumerable<T> collection) { this.collection = collection; }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return collection.GetEnumerator(); }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    }
}
```

**On a related note:** how can a custom collection which implements `IEnumerable<T>` expose its own `Count` property in such a way that the CLR `Count()` extension method can take advantage of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't look for a `Count` property by name, but it does check whether it implements [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx), and then uses that type's `Count` property. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx):

> If the type of source implements
>   `ICollection<T>`, that
>   implementation is used to obtain the
>   count of elements. Otherwise, this
>   method determines the count.

(Obviously this only applies to the overload which doesn't take a predicate.)

So, if you want to obtain the count efficiently, make sure you implement `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Here is the source code that confirms the answer and documentation:
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Enumerable.Count method will indeed look for `ICollection<T>` and use it's Count property if found.  You can verify this by looking at Enumerable.Count in reflector.

This is only true though if you use the Count extension method which takes no additional parameters.  If you use the version which takes a predicate it will walk the enumerable elements.