# LINQ Count .. best method

Tags: vb.net, linq, performance

My company has just started using LINQ and I still am having a little trouble with the abstractness (if thats a word) of the LINQ command and the SQL, my question is

```
  Dim query = (From o In data.Addresses _
                    Select o.Name).Count
```

In the above in my mind, the SQL is returning all rows and the does a count on the number rows in the IQueryable result, so I would be better with

```
    Dim lstring = Aggregate o In data.Addresses _
    Into Count()
```

Or am I over thinking the way LINQ works ? Using VB Express at home so I can't see the actual SQL that is being sent to the database (I think) as I don't have access to the SQL profiler

Comment: Completely without being a shill (zero affiliation), I suggest you take a look at LINQPad - http://www.linqpad.net/ which does allow you to view the generated SQL from a LINQ to SQL expression, for both VB and C#, making it somewhat easier to work on query snippets without rebuilding/rerunning.

Comment: @Marc Thanks, that allowed me to answer the question myself .... nice tool .... ps, make it an answer so I can tick it please :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned, these are functionally equivalent, one just uses query syntax.

As mentioned in my comment, if you evaluate the following as a VB Statement(s) in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
Dim lstring = Aggregate o In Test _
    Into Count()
```

You get this in the generated SQL output window:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Test] AS [t0]
```

Which is the same as the following VB LINQ expression as evaluated:

```
(From o In Test_
    Select o.Symbol).Count
```

You get the exact same result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Visual Basic, but based on

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546138.aspx

Those two approaches are the same. One uses method syntax and the other uses query syntax.

You can find out for sure by using SQL Profiler as the queries run.

PS - The "point" of LINQ is you can easily do query operations without leaving code/VB-land.

Comment: Cheers but from that I can't see the it talks about .Count, using express at the moment so don't have access to the profiler (must spend money) .. PS I got your PS, should have said "Or am I not understanding the way LINQ Works"

Answer (score 1):

An important thing here, is that the code you give will work with a wide variety of data sources. It will hopefully do so in a very efficient way, though that can't be fully guaranteed. It certainly will be done in an efficient way with a SQL source (being converted into a `SELECT COUNT(*)` SQL query. It will be done efficiently if the source was an in-memory collection (it gets converted to calling the `Count` property). It isn't done very efficiently if the source is an enumerable that is not a collection (in this case it does read everything and count as it goes), but in that case there really isn't a more efficient way of doing this.

In each case it has done the same conceptual operation, in the most efficient manner possible, without you having to worry about the details. No big deal with counting, but a bigger deal in more complex cases.

To a certain extent, you are right when you say "in my mind, the SQL is returning all rows and the does a count on the number rows". *Conceptually* that is what is happening in that query, but the implementation may differ. Compare with how the real query in SQL may not match the literal interpretation of the SQL command, to allow the most efficient approach to be picked.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I think the one thing that I have learned in the last month or so of using LinQ is not to presume what the SQL being produced is (and to keep away from none iQueryable object types as long as possible)

Comment: Yep. Indeed, sometimes when I do look at the SQL produced and it seems a bit strange, then going to the next level down and looking at the query plan shows that actually, the LINQ produced SQL is better than the more obvious approach. It is worth looking at the SQL produced, esp. for more complex or frequently hit queries, as you may be able to help it with appropriate indexing and statistics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point as Linq with SQL has late binding the search is done when you need it so when you say I need the count number then a Query is created.

Before that Linq for SQL creates Expression trees that will be "translated" in to SQL when you need it....

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx

How to debug see Scott 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx
[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/linqtosql3/step5.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Does that answer the above question ?

Comment: Sorry, the reason that I ask the question is that when I put the dubugger or .string on "Dim query = (From o In data.Addresses Select o.Name).Count" I get 2 which is the result, when I do the same for the other query I get the expected "select count(*)" sql, so I am leaning to the latter being better .... but as I can't access the profiler, I can't determine

Comment: Try use the logging on the context object ....

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQ2Log4Net.aspx

Comment: Best tool to learn is LinqPad 
http://www.linqpad.net/

or use the debug window 

 var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
 db.Log = sw;

see 
http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers

Comment: Another stackflow entry that discuss Count

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651301/c-count-extension-method-performance