# How to get a count of the items returned by a LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to get the count of the items returned by a LINQ query. I would assume it is .Count but apparently not.
I am loading a DataTable from Excel then getting the distinct rows based on an identifier.  I am now trying to get a count of the items returned. `Leases`  contains the data of whose rows I would like a count of.  I tried a few things (now commented out) but have been unsuccessful.

Perhaps a LINQ expert can help me out?

Here is my code:

```
Dim Leases As Object
Dim dtData As System.Data.DataTable = LoadExcelAsDb(oFile.FullName)
Try
    ' How many leases are there
    Leases = From row In dtData.AsEnumerable() Select row.Field(Of Object)("F2") Distinct
    '    LeaseCt = New System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(Of Object)(Leases).Items.count 
    '    LeaseCt = New System.Linq.Enumerable(Of Object)(Leases).Items.count
    '    LeaseCt = Leases.Count
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.WriteLine("Error reading files" + ex.ToString)
End Try

''' <summary>
''' Loads an excel file as a datatable
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sFilename">Filename of excel to be loaded </param>   
''' <returns>Populated Datatable</returns>
Private Function LoadExcelAsDb(sFilename As String) As System.Data.DataTable
    ' Connect to Excel get table
    Dim oConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilename + " ; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    Dim oCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", oConnection)

    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataTable = New System.Data.DataTable
    Try
        oCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Error reading files" + ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Return DtSet
End Function
```

Comment: Try using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153641/linq-count-best-method

Comment: `Leases` is going to be an "in memory query" - it wont have a count until you execute it.  `LeaseCt = (Leases).Count()` will give you the count for *that* query

Comment: `LeaseCt = Leases.ToList().Count()`

Comment: When I try Leases.ToList().Count() I get an error saying Tolist is not available

Comment: When I try LeaseCt = (Leases).Count() I get the error "Public member 'Count' on type 'Integer' not found."

Comment: Where is `Leases` defined?  The code you posted doesn't define it so it must be defined globally somewhere.  What is its data type?  Turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: It is defined further up :  Dim Leases  its a variant

Comment: Off-topic: why do you place the most exception-sensitive part outside the try-catch? On-topic: why not simply `Dim Leases = From row In .....`? And then `Lease.Count`.

Comment: I don't think the position of the Dim is important. it would not change the problem I am having if I dimensioned in the try catch.  But to answer your question I need the variable Leases to exist outside the try catch as it will be used many times.

Comment: It will change the type of the variable, that's the point here. Declare it by its correct compile-time type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary concept that you need to grasp when working with LINQ is that the object being queried must be enumerable.  This means that as a minimum it implements the interface [System.Collections.IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx).  Preferably, the queried object will implement the [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

in your LINQ statement:

`Leases = From row In dtData.AsEnumerable() Select row.Field(Of Object)("F2") Distinct`

the queried object is the result `dtData.AsEnumerable()`.  The Datatable extension method `AsEnumerable` returns a [System.Data.EnnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979(v=vs.110).aspx), so the `row` variable in the statement is of type `DataRow`.

The statement *selects* `row.Field(Of Object)("F2")`.  Since this returns a single object of type System.Object, the query result will be of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)`.  However, you are assigning the result to the variable `Leases` that you have defined this way:

`Dim Leases As Object`

There is not much you can do with the variable declared this way.  It would be better is you declared it to be the type returned from the query.

`Dim Leases As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)`.

Defined this way, the `Leases` would be extensible by the methods declared in the [System.Linq.Enumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) class that would allow calling the [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Typically DataTable with ADO.NET and Linq do not play nice with newer well typed structures that are generally something like List(Of (PocoObject)).  However typically you can cheat it in my experience with something like:

```
Sub Main()
   Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
   dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)))
   Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
   row("Id") = 1
   dt.Rows.Add(row)
   Dim row2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
   row2("Id") = 2
   dt.Rows.Add(row2)

   'Shows 2 rows
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Select().ToList().Count)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

The key is a DataTable HAS NO 'ToList()' extension until you 'Select' stuff from it.  DataTable with Linq IMHO is like driving a car the wrong way down a highway.  Because nothing is well typed and as an example with some production code I have to get something out of a 'DataSet' I have in a WinForm solution and then just get a particular set of columns out to a POCO Object to make lists I would have to do something like this:

```
Dim ls = ds.Tables("tProduct").Select().Select(Function(x) New Product With {.ProductID = CInt(x("ProductId")?.ToString), .ProductDesc = x("ProductName")?.ToString}).ToList()
```

Fun stuff.  Notice the double select(), that is not a typo.  One is an extension off of System.Data.DataTable and one is from System.Linq.Enumerable.  So you need to Select before you can select lol.

Comment: Thanks this is very useful!