# In .NET, is it better to call .Count() or, when available, .Count?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, count

When the Linq namespace is imported, it is possible to use both .Count() and .Count (on objects that implement IList for example).

.Count() will call the .Count property, if available, as per:
[C# Count() Extension Method Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651301/c-count-extension-method-performance)

Is it better then to directly use .Count over .Count(), for a (small) performance gain?

**Update**: interesting performance figures here (1-2 orders of magnitude): [Is the Linq Count() faster or slower than List.Count or Array.Length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981254/is-the-linq-count-faster-or-slower-than-list-count-or-array-length/985279#985279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My personal preference is to stick with the existing methods and properties if they are available without casting. Therefore I'd use `Count`.

Answer (score 6):

The performance will be the same, as the `Count()` extension methods checks wether it is an `ICollection` and uses the `Count` property if it is (this is for the .net linq stack).

Reference: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) (Remarks)

Comment: Well, it will perform an additional method call and issue a cast, so it isn't the *same* really. But I agree that for normal use the difference will be of no importance.

Comment: Yes, that's correct of course. However, if you feel compelled to optimize on an method call, you might have bigger problems at hand.

Comment: More correct to say "the performance will be the same if list implements ICollection"

Answer (score 1):

I use .Count when I don't want to filter a count, then use the Query Extension when I do want a filtered count.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely .Count is better when it is available. However, you don't know if .Count is a property that is derived from a function upon accession.

Since .Count is most likely predetermined before you call it, it should be more efficient if the previous isn't the case.