# Is it worth caching the result of .Count (or .Count()) when the operation is O(1)?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, count

If .Count or .Count() is used several times on objects that implement ICollection (therefore with O(1) computational complexity, unless of course it has been overriden), is it better performance-wise (not memory wise), even for a very small difference, to cache the value in a temporary variable rather than accessing the property value each time it is needed?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical or some kind of philosophical question?

Comment: ICollection objects almost always cache the count themselves in a backing field, which Count returns.

Comment: @AresAvatar: For every object that implements `ICollection<T>` and caches its count, I can make an object that implements `ICollection<T>` and doesn't cache its count, and I can make retrieving the count painfully slow. Your statement that it "almost always caches the count" is false.

Comment: The prequel: [In .NET, is it better to call .Count() or, when available, .Count?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6793422/60761)

Comment: @Jason - yes you *could*, which is why I said "almost always".  But that would be a very badly written class that would perform very poorly, so you probably *wouldn't*.

Comment: @AresAvatar: No, if I can make one that is evil for every one that is not, there are at least as many evil ones as there are not evil ones. Again, that makes the statement "almost always" false.

Comment: @Jason - you are completely wrong.  One *can* do lots of bad things in code.  That doesn't mean one *does*, and even if one *does*, their code gets tossed because it works poorly.

Comment: @AresAvatar: Please point to a particular statement that I made that is "completely wrong." Thanks!

Comment: @Jason: "if I can make one that is evil for every one that is not, there are at least as many evil ones as there are not evil ones." This statement implying your capability to write bad code means there are at least as many bad collections as good ones, is completely wrong. Most coders would never write an evil collection like this and even you wouldn't. At least I hope so! So your assertion that as many such evil collections as good ones exist, is completely wrong.

Comment: @AresAvatar: Again, you don't get it. It has nothing to do with writing bad code. Just because the example I gave no one would ever, ever, ever write or use in production code doesn't mean there aren't collections out there for which `ICollection<T>` is not `O(1)`. Is that really so hard for you to understand?

Comment: @Jason - one doesn't waste time or effort or write unnecessary defensive code over every possibility of bad code.  Is that so hard for you to understand?

Comment: @Jason let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1746/discussion-between-aresavatar-and-jason)

Comment: @AresAvatar: I know, which is why I said in my answer, **I wouldn't worry about this unless I knew I might be getting in evil collections, and I found it to be a significant performance bottleneck.** (bold in original). I also said: Just write the simplest code that works (use `ICollection<T>.Count`). If and only if it's a performance bottleneck in your application would I worry about tuning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it could be (very slightly) faster, since the overhead of a method call, associated error checking, and (in the case of Count()) the dynamic type checking for ICollection have some amount of overhead.

Is it worth it though? That's entirely up to you and your application. If you're in a very tight inner loop, it might be worth it. Then again, on more recent .NET runtimes, this sort of trivial property will probably get inlined in such circumstances.

As always, let your profiler tell you where the hotspots are in your application.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question directly, even an O(1) operation can take a long time to complete; it's just that it always takes the same time no matter how big the collection. Caching the result and reading it back is going to be fast, always, but not guaranteed to be faster than any given O(1) operation. You need some timings first ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it's a mistake to think that `ICollection.Count` is `O(1)`. It morally should be, but there's no guarantee that it is:

```
public EvilCollection<T> : ICollection<T> {
    private readonly ICollection<T> collection;
    private readonly Func<int, int> slowGrowingFunction;
    public EvilCollection(
        ICollection<T> collection,
        Func<int, int> slowGrowingFunction) 
    {
        this.collection = collection;
        this.slowGrowingFunction = slowGrowingFunction;
    }

    public int Count {
        get {
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * this.slowGrowingFunction(this.collection.Count));
            return this.collection.Count;
        }
    }

    // other methods wrap methods on collection for ICollection<T>
}

ICollection<T> evilCollection = 
    new EvilCollection<T>(collection, n => Ackermann(4, n));
```

Oh no, `evilCollection.Count` is `O(Ackermann(4, n))`!

That said, **I wouldn't worry about this unless I knew I might be getting in evil collections, and I found it to be a significant performance bottleneck.** Keep in mind, the code is less clear, it could be less correct (what is the count updates after you've cached the result?), etc.

Just write the simplest code that works (use `ICollection<T>.Count`). If and only if it's a performance bottleneck in your application would I worry about tuning it.

Comment: No one should write a collection like this.  You even admit that by calling it evil.  A collection you had to count every time would properly be defined as an Enumerable rather than collection or list.

Comment: You're missing the point. It's false to assume that `ICollection<T>.Count` is `O(1)`. It's false because I can make one example that is not. This isn't the only example (it's just egregious), and there could even be real-world examples. But if you are coding to the interface `ICollection<T>`, you have no, No, NO idea what is coming in. You have no idea if it's an `EvilCollection<T>`, or if it's something else that makes `ICollection<T>.Count` not be `O(1)`. Thus, you can't make the blanket assumption that `ICollection<T>.Count` is `O(1)` and then start noodling from that false assumption.

Comment: Jason, yes, you CAN make that assumption. All code needs to be run and tested. When your evil collection behaved poorly (not only in the OP's use, but in many common uses) it would be thrown out or defensively coded against, for example by writing a wrapper class that properly cached Count.

Comment: @AresAvatar: You can not make that assumption. Here's my method. I'm an API writer, or a framework writer or who knows what. In my API I provide this method: `public void M(ICollection<T> collection)` I have no idea what `collection` is going to be. None. I can not assume within my method `M` that `collection.Count` is `O(1)`. I can't because I don't know what `collection` is at runtime. Don't you get that?

Comment: I consider you to be wrong in this matter and I don't think we're going to agree.  I will not comment further.

Comment: @AresAvatar: Good for you. The fact that you can't point to a single false statement should tell you there is something wrong with your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no need; there's no benefit to using a temporary variable.  Additionally, if you're caching your count, you run the risk of the count being incorrect if the collection set changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO** if you are sure what `.Count()` will be doing now and in the feature. The answer is **YES** if `.Count()` is some implementation that may change. Let's say you change the implementation with some LinkedList which may not be O(1).