# Excel data entry from List<[]> is slow, is there a better algorithm design for this?

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-4.0

I have an algorithm that takes a list of arrays and enters them into an Excel file, however it is very slow. Is there a better design for this algorithm?

```
public void WriteToExcel(List<string[]> parsedData, string path, string fileName)
{
    // Get the Excel application object.
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

    // Make Excel visible.
    xlApp.Visible = true;

    Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[1];
    sheet.Select(Type.Missing);
    //Loop through arrays in parsedData list.
    for (var lstElement=0;lstElement<parsedData.Count;lstElement++)
    {
        //Loop through array.
        for(var arryElement = 0; arryElement<parsedData[lstElement].Count(); arryElement++)
        {
            sheet.Cells[lstElement + 1, arryElement + 1] = parsedData[lstElement][arryElement];
        }
    }
    // Save the changes and close the workbook.
    workbook.Close(true, fileName, Type.Missing);

    // Close the Excel server.
    xlApp.Quit();

}
```

Comment: Working with Excel using interop is slow and messy. If you can restrict yourself to supporting only the newer .xlsx file format, have a look at the excellent and free EPPlus https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Comment: although probably will not improve performance significantly, you should be using `parsedData[lstElement].Length` instead of `parsedData[lstElement].Count()`. The later would actually iterate through the array which is a bit slower.

Comment: Actually, it will not iterate the entire array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651301/c-sharp-count-extension-method-performance

Comment: @EricJ.  My boss does not want me using an3rd party libraries, otherwise I would.

Comment: Thanks @EricJ., Didn't know that. This is the case it seems for classes that implement the `ICollection` interface.

Comment: @YacoubMassad This actually did improve performance a bit. However it is still very slow.

Comment: If feasible for you you'll get much better performance if you can emit your data into a file format that Excel understands (e.g. CSV) and then instruct Excel to load that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with Office interop, the slowest part are the inter process calls which happen anytime you access some property or method of the automation class/interface.

So the optimization goal should be to minimize the roundtrips (inter process calls).

In your particular use case, instead of setting values cell by cell (i.e. doing a lot of calls), there is fortunately a way to set values of a whole Excel range with one call by passing array of values. Depending of how many columns contains your data, the following modification should give you a significant speedup.

The significant part:

```
//Loop through arrays in parsedData list.
int row = 1, column = 1;
object[] values = null; // buffer - see below. Avoids unnecessary allocations.
for (var lstElement = 0; lstElement < parsedData.Count; lstElement++)
{
    var data = parsedData[lstElement];
    if (data == null || data.Length == 0) continue;
    if (data.Length == 1)
    {
        // Single cell
        sheet.Cells[row, column] = data[0];
    }
    else
    {
        // Cell range
        var range = sheet.Range[CellName(row, column), CellName(row, column + data.Length - 1)];
        // We can pass the data array directly, but since it's a string[], Excel will treat them as text.
        // The trick is to to pass them via object[].
        if (values == null || values.Length != data.Length)
            values = new object[data.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            values[i] = data[i];
        // Set all values in a single roundtrip
        range.Value2 = values;
    }
    row++;
}
```

Helpers used:

```
static string CellName(int row, int column)
{
    return ColumnName(column) + row;
}

static string ColumnName(int column)
{
    const int StartLetter = 'A', EndLetter = 'Z', LetterCount = EndLetter - StartLetter + 1;
    int index = column - 1;
    var letter = (char)(StartLetter + (index % LetterCount));
    if (index < LetterCount) return letter.ToString();
    var firstLetter = (char)(StartLetter + index / LetterCount - 1);
    return new string(new [] { firstLetter, letter });
}
```

Once you get the idea, you can get even better performance by extending the above to handle multi row ranges like this (the most important thing in this case is to use 2d array for values):

```
const int MaxCells = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // Arbitrary
var maxColumns = parsedData.Max(data => data.Length);
var maxRows = Math.Min(parsedData.Count, MaxCells / maxColumns);
object[,] values = null;
int row = 1, column = 1;
for (int lstElement = 0; lstElement < parsedData.Count; )
{
    int rowCount = Math.Min(maxRows, parsedData.Count - lstElement);
    if (values == null || values.GetLength(0) != rowCount)
        values = new object[rowCount, maxColumns];
    for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
    {
        var data = parsedData[lstElement++];
        for (int c = 0; c < data.Length; c++)
            values[r, c] = data[c];
    }
    var range = sheet.Range[CellName(row, column), CellName(row + rowCount - 1, column + maxColumns - 1)];
    range.Value2 = values;
    row += rowCount;
}
```

Comment: Spot on.  Every call to `Cells`, `Range, `Value`, etc is an expensive COM call.  My experience is that 70-90% of the time spent in these types of methods can be eliminated by pulling the data out as an array, manipulating the array, and putting the data back.

Comment: The same works when you need to modify a range from VBA _within_ Excel by the way. Regarding your answer: instead of the helper methods, you  may want to consider using the `R1C1` notation

Comment: @CompuChip Of course `R1C1` would be easier. But the documentation states that `Range` method expects `A1` style and my experiments show that it really does. Also note that even if `R1C1` style worked, I would still not use it directly in the code, but encapsulate inside the `CellName` helper method.

Comment: @IvanStoev and there is also a `Cells` property that takes two indices, and `Range` can also be created from two `Cells`. Anyway, just minor details; still a great answer.

Comment: @CompuChip It's interesting discussion though:) I am lazy (like any normal developer) and will not write a code if not necessary. While what you say could allow me to avoid writing that (simple) function, don't you think it would kill the primary goal - less roundtrips? `Range` + `Cells` + `Cells` are 3 roundtrips (and COM objects to be maintained - you know, `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` etc.) compared to 1 with the help of that little helper. Working with OLE automation (especially out of process) does not follow the normal programming practices. Luckily I don't have to use it in my project:)

Comment: @IvanStoev it _is_ an interesting discussion and you have a very good point there. Until you find yourself in a position like I found myself once, where you have to debug an Excel sheet and it turns out it was written for Excel 200x in which you could never go beyond column `AV` or so, and stuff just broke with column names like `AAA` that were possible in later vresions of Excel (and of course, used by users).