# Create Excel Sheet From a DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datatable, excel-interop

I am facing a strange phenomenon.
I wrote a method that copy values from datatable to an excel sheet.
The problem is that the rows are copied to columns and columns to rows.

For example:

DataTable:

```
Item   Quantity    UnitPrice   TotalPrice
A      10          2           20
B      3           15          45
C      100         0.5         50
```

Excel Sheet:

```
Item   Quantity    UnitPrice   TotalPrice
A      B          C           
10     3          100          
2      15         0.5         
20     45         50
```

My code:

```
 private void PopulateDataWorkSheet()
        {
        xl.Workbooks xlWorkbooks = _xlApp.Workbooks;
        xl.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(_excelFileName);
        xl.Sheets xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets;
        const int startRowIndex = 2;    // first row for columns title
        const int startColumnIndex = 1;

        xl.Worksheet xlDataWorkSheet = xlSheets[DATA_SHEET];
        xl.Range xlCells = xlDataWorkSheet.Cells;

        for (var rowindex = 0; rowindex < _datatable.Rows.Count; rowindex++)
        {
            for (var columnindex = 0; columnindex < _datatable.Columns.Count; columnindex++)
            {
                xlCells[startRowIndex + rowindex][startColumnIndex + columnindex] = _datatable.Rows[rowindex][columnindex];
            }
        }

        xlWorkbook.Save();
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        xlWorkbooks.Close();

        ReleaseExcelObject(xlCells);
        ReleaseExcelObject(xlDataWorkSheet);
        ReleaseExcelObject(xlSheets);
        ReleaseExcelObject(xlWorkbook);
        ReleaseExcelObject(xlWorkbooks);
    }
```

I can simply solve it by changing as following but I am not clear what is wrong:

```
xlCells[startColumnIndex + columnindex][startRowIndex + rowindex] = _datatable.Rows[rowindex][columnindex];
```

Did I miss something in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am facing a strange phenomenon. Did I miss something in my code?

Welcome to the world of Excel `Range`, dynamics, optional parameters and COM object `Default` member concept.

Excel `Range` is a strange thing. Almost every method/property returns another range. The indexer you used is something like this

```
dynamic this[object RowIndex, object ColumnIndex = Type.Missing] { get; set; }
```

i.e. has required row index and optional column index.

Let take this call

```
xlCells[startRowIndex + rowindex][startColumnIndex + columnindex] = ...;
```

it's equivalent to something like this

```
var range1 = (Excel.Range)xlCells[startRowIndex + rowindex];
var range2 = (Excel.Range)range1[startColumnIndex + columnindex];
//                               ^^^^^^
// this is treated as row index offset from the range1
range2.Value2 = ...;
```

Shortly, you need to change it to

```
xlCells[startRowIndex + rowindex, startColumnIndex + columnindex] = ...;
```

Comment: Do you mean that range1 is actually the entire column with index=current rowindex?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure what's the default treatment of `ColumnIndex` when not specified, the dynamic view of the `range1` shows `Count=1`, `Column=1`.

Comment: You are welcome. In case at some point you have performance issue with the above, you may take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352783/excel-data-entry-from-list-is-slow-is-there-a-better-algorithm-design-for-t/35366999#35366999) for faster technique which in your case can be combined with `DataRow.ItemArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change how you access your excel cells. 
`cells[StartRowIndex+ rowindex, StartColumnIndex + columnindex]` is Row first and then column. What you do is `cells[StartRowIndex + rowindex][StartColumnIndex + columnindex]` which takes the column as a first argument.

The order of the loops does not matter at all.. so the right solution would be:

```
  for (var rowindex = 0; rowindex < _datatable.Rows.Count; rowindex++)
        {
            for (var columnindex = 0; columnindex < _datatable.Columns.Count; columnindex++)
            {
                xlCells[startRowIndex + rowindex, startColumnIndex + columnindex] = _datatable.Rows[rowindex][columnindex];
            }
        }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You doing it wrong, you need to go like this:

```
                for (var columnindex = 0; columnindex < _datatable.Columns.Count; columnindex++)
                {
                    for (var rowindex = 0; rowindex < _datatable.Rows.Count; rowindex++)
                    {
                            xlCells[startRowIndex + rowindex][startColumnIndex + columnindex] = _datatable.Rows[rowindex][columnindex];
                    }
                }
```

you need the column and then the row.

Comment: No you are wrong. It doesn't matter in what order you get the indices, it does matter how you insert it. Did you test it?

Comment: Think about it, at a table of 3X3, you need to go at (0,0) -> (1,0) -> (2,0) -> (0,1) -> so on..., so the column before. And it matter, become you need the row to increase before the column.

Comment: Yes, I though about it and it is wrong because also the indices of xlCells are reversed accordingly. To be sure, I checked it and it doesn't work as well

Comment: Reilly, ok... an exception throw?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to overcome the problem.It works fine for me.

```
                xlApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                // Create workbook .  
                xlWorkBook = xlApplication.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

                // Get active sheet from workbook  
                xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
                xlWorkSheet.Name = "Report";
                xlWorkSheet.Columns.ColumnWidth = 30;


                xlApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < gridViewDataTable.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                {
                    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < gridViewDataTable.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
                    {
                        if (rowIndex == 0)
                        {
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 1, colIndex + 1] = gridViewDataTable.Columns[colIndex].ColumnName;
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 1, colIndex + 1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                        }
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 2, colIndex + 1].Borders.Color = Color.Black;
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 2, colIndex + 1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 2, colIndex + 1] = gridViewDataTable.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex];  
                    }
                }
                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filename);
                xlWorkBook.Close();
                xlApplication.Quit();
```